# Double insertion in database after a user double click a button

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

I work on website where people can subscribe to a tournament by clicking on a link triggering an AJAX POST request. 
The application is built with Spring MVC and Hibernate.

Sometimes, probably when a user double click, he is registered twice in database. 
I tried to put some javascript safeties but it seems to not be enough.

So I guess, both requests are played almost simultaneously and the second one pass the isUserAlreadySubscribed test before the first one is saved in database.

Is there a way with Hibernate to put a kind of token on this specific method? Maybe something related to the session too?

below, the service method called by the controller.

```
@Override
@Transactional
public boolean joinTournament(String username, Long eventId, String date, Long barId) {
        [... check if tournament exists ...] 
        if (!isUserAlreadySubscribed(tournament, username)) {
            //On enregistre le user comme inscrit
            TournamentPlayer tournamentPlayer = new TournamentPlayer();
            tournamentPlayer.setPresent(false);
            tournamentPlayer.setTournament(tournament);
            com.meltdown.users.domain.User user = hibernateUserDao.findByUsername(username);
            tournamentPlayer.setUser(user);
            java.util.Date today = new java.util.Date();
            tournamentPlayer.setCreatedAt(new Timestamp(today.getTime()));
            hibernateTournamentDao.createTournamentPlayer(tournamentPlayer);
            tournament.getPlayers().add(tournamentPlayer);

            hibernateTournamentDao.editTournament(tournament);

            [... send mail ...]
            return true;
        }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Do you use JPA entity classes? If yes, then are you using version annotation or version field ( http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Version.html ) ?

Comment: I use JPA entity but not the @Version annotation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are already using declarative transaction management with the `Transactional` annotation. So you probably want to look into what [isolation level](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_(database_systems)#Isolation_levels) you want to use. Just as a test to see if it fixes your issue, you can change that method to use the strictest isolation:

```
@Transactional(isolation=Isolation.SERIALIZABLE)
```

If that is successful, you can downgrade to a more performant level such as `READ_COMMITTED`.

Comment: I was not able to lower the level of isolation tough

Comment: @Labe - probably want to fix your javascript next

Comment: I started by adding javascript mechanics but it seems to not completly fix the problem 

$aSubscribeBtn.click(function(e) {
            this.disabled = true;
            e.preventDefault();
[...]

Comment: @Labe just open a new question for the javascript; it is probably a pretty easy fix